# [Flow]Share type definitions among libs

Tags: reactjs, react-native, flowtype

It seems type definitions cannot share among different lib file. Is this a bug or any other extra configurations are needed?

#### ./flow/dto/ProductDTO.js

```
// @flow
export type ProductDTO = {
  id: number,
  name: string,
  img: string,
}

export type TestState = {
  products: Array<ProductDTO>,
}
```

#### ./flow/redux/ProductStates.js

```
// @flow
// I even tried to import type { .ProductDTO } from '../dto/ProductDTO';
export type ProductState = {
  products: Array<ProductDTO>,
}
```

#### example.js

```
// @flow
const Test1: TestState = {
  products: ['xxx'], // flow error report here as expected
}

const Test2: ProductState = {
  products: ['xxx'], // no error, it seems flow does not recognize ProductState
}
```

#### .flowconfig

...

[libs]

flow

...